# Django matching query does not exist but I get prints

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

models.py

```
class SessaoAtividade(models.Model): # Activity_Session
   id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
   atividadeid = models.ForeignKey(Atividade, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='AtividadeID')

class Atividade(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
```

code in a view.py

```
for a in atividades:                
            #print(a.id)
            sessao_atividade = SessaoAtividade.objects.get(atividadeid=a.id)
```

So, basically I am using this queryset to get SessaoAtividade objects. It returns me "SessaoAtividade matching query does not exist."

But if I print with "print(a.id)" I get prints in the console

Why is this happening ?

Comment: you'll need to explain more. what is in `atividades` list? already `SessaoAtividade` objects? other objects, but what kind of? if they are other objects, a DoesNotExist could easily happen?!

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if `atividadeid` is equals to `a.id` which is not working, because `atividadeid` is an object, not integer.

You have to compare `atividadeid__id` with `a.id`

Simply:
`sessao_atividade = SessaoAtividade.objects.get(atividadeid__id=a.id)`

Also please remember that `SessaoAtividade.objects.get(atividadeid__id=a.id)` can throw DoesNotExist exception

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `atividades` is a object list of class `Atividade`, you actually don't need to search using `a.id`. you can search using your object instance as in your model you have defined it as an object not an integer.

```
sessao_atividade = SessaoAtividade.objects.get(atividadeid=a)
```

should work. Also I would suggest to use `filter` instead of `get` that way you don't need to worry about `DoesNotExist` exception and also if there are multiple objects with same `atividadeid`.